# Android source code - Copying downloaded code to mirror

Tags: android, android-source

I have already downloaded Android source code using
`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1`

Now I want to create a mirror for other people to access over LAN
`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest --mirror`

Can I copy already downloaded source inside mirror dir so that download usage will be low?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you can. The only thing that you should do is to correct manifest file. For instance, you can read [here](http://www.omappedia.org/wiki/Android_Miscellaneous) how to do this.

Comment: That link explains setup of mirror. I wanted to use existing (downloaded) source code files while setting up mirror. `repo init` should use local files (downloaded source code) while mirroring. I was hoping that this may reduce network traffic.

Comment: The best way to test this is to check )